# How to send keystroke using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I have screen capture software `picPick` and I've set hot key to take scrollable shots with
**CTRL + ALT + PRINT_SCREEN** buttons.

My goal is to run the application, then press **hotkey** to capture the screen.
But seems picPick is ran but SendKeys() are not doing anything I think, nothing occurs,
what am I doing wrong?

**VBScript**

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run "C:\picPick"
WshShell.SendKeys("+^{PRTSC}")
```

I also tried simple print screen,

```
WshShell.SendKeys("{PRTSC}")
```

Then tried paste what I got onto MS Paint but nothing happened (i.e. screenshot btn wasn't pressed I believe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is stated in the [`SendKeys` method description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83.aspx):

> You cannot send the PRINT SCREEN key {PRTSC} to an application.

The {PRTSC} code is probably reserved for future use, like in .NET [`SendKeys.Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for insight... that's quite lame ... :(