# VBScript keypress- how?

Tags: vbscript, keypress

I am quite new to VBScript and I'm looking to learn, so please keep it as simple as possible.
(I'm sorry, but I just don't understand many examples provided by others.)

Basically, I'm trying to run

```
Set wshShell = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
do 
wscript.sleep 9000  
wshshell.sendkeys "2" 

loop
```

(its longer, I've just shortened our parts you don't need to see.)

I want to make it so that when I press the = key it will run the code, activating the keypress of the number 2.

For clarification on the loop part, I want it so that once I press = it will send the key 2 over and over without needing the press of = again.

A stop function would be very handy too!

Comment: Are you just getting into programming, or just new to VBScript? (I can produce an example, just trying to gauge the detail I should go into)

Comment: Quite new to programming in general.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send keystroke using VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137095/how-to-send-keystroke-using-vbscript)

Answer (score 1):

It could be complicated to wait for a keypress in VBS.
First, you need to loop to catch the pressed key, then you have to make annother loop (sleep 9000 and sendkeys "2") and finaly, find a way to stop the loop.
There is a example here: [Need to sense a keystroke in VBscript to end a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727406/need-to-sense-a-keystroke-in-vbscript-to-end-a-loop).

If it's possible I advise you to use a HTA page with two buttons (start loop and stop loop) instead of waiting for a key to be pressed. 
Here is how to do this: [How to stop a loop when pressing "OK" on a message box with VBS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146772/how-to-stop-a-loop-when-pressing-ok-on-a-message-box-with-vbs/44376414#44376414)

You need a HTA file (same thing as html but is standalone, not runed from a web browser and the extension is ".hta").

Comment: Thank you! Now, I know that this is a VERY noobish question but how can I fix this? http://prntscr.com/jiy6z3 I know I need something along the lines of Set wshShell = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  but I can't figure out where or how to put it. Apart form that, it works perfectly. @Tommy

Comment: You have to remove "wscript": Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").
Same thing for wscript.sleep.

WScript doesn't work with a HTA but there is alternative command.

Because you have the "sleep(time)" function, you don't need "wscript" anymore. Juste remove it and your code will work right after.